# Cant get if sentence to work?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I am using a foreach loop to run through an array. With it I have $q which iterates with a value of 1 on every loop run. And when the value reaches 1/3 of the total, it is to echo out new div, in order to make several columns.
But I cant seem to find the error.

```
            $i = 0;
            $count = count($segments->getItems());
            $countdiv = $count / 3;
            $countdiv = number_format((float)$countdiv,0,',','');
            $q = 0;
                foreach($segments->getItems() as $segment) 
                {
                    $q++;
                    $allusers = 0;
                    if($segment->getName() === 'All Users') {
                        $allusers = "checked";
                    }

                    ?>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $segment->getName();?>" value="segments[]" class="custom-control-input" <?php echo $allusers?>>
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        <span class="custom-control-description"><?php echo $segment->getName();?></span>
                      </label>
                    <?php
                    if($q === $countdiv) 
                    {
                        ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
                            <?php
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: I'd try `if($q % (round($count) / 3) === 0)`, which would let you remove `$countdiv` altogether.

Comment: `$q === $countdiv` will never be true because you're try to **strictly** compare a string to an integer.

Comment: @ChrisForrence If he's trying to perform something when it reaches 1/3 of the count, how would `if($q % $count === 0)` work? Let's say the count is `9`, and the iteration is `3`, the result would be 3, which wouldn't give him the results he's asking for.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yeah, I see the edit now. I wrote the comment out slightly after you commented and clicked submit but my office internet decided to not function and when my browser restarted, apparently it submitted it. That's the only reason I even saw it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number_format()` returns a formatted **string** of the number. So when you then compare that **string** to an actual **number** using `===`, it will always be false, since a string type can never be strictly equivalent to a number type. Also, it would only work the first time around as `$q` is always increasing.

As @Chris Forrence recommends you can do:

`if(($q % round($count / 3)) === 0)`

Let's dive into that a little bit. First we divide `$count` by 3 since we want three columns. We can't divide on a fraction of an item, so let's `round` that result to a whole number. We then use that to take the modulo (`%`) of `$q`. This just says divide `x / y` but instead of the result, give me the remainder. So each time that `$q` is a multiple of `$count / 3` this will return 0. So, if we test that whole calculation to see if it equals `0` then we will know when we've hit one of our column boundaries.

If you're looping over a large amount of objects and performance becomes an issue, change your `$countdiv` declaration to be:

`$countdiv = round($count / 3)`

And then the above if statement can be cut down to:

`if(($q % $countdiv) === 0)`